# Serialize form as json without empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, serialization

I have a HTML form with 3 fields. I want to serialize them as json object (that works so far using my `getFormData($form)` method. But now I want to exclude all fields without inputtext/value in my form.

**This serializes my form and saves it as json object:**

```
function getFormData($form){
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    return indexed_array;
}
```

**This is how I tried to filter fields without value:**

```
var form = $("#bulk-edit-fut-account-form :input[value!='']");
console.log(JSON.stringify(form));
var formData = getFormData(form);
```

**My HTML form:**

```
<form id="bulk-edit-fut-account-form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Id<span class="asterisk">*</span></label><div class="col-sm-9"><input id="bulkAccountIds" type="text" required="" readonly="" value="118 119 " data-id="[{&quot;Id&quot;:118},{&quot;Id&quot;:119}]" class="form-control valid" aria-required="true"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Max. Requests / minute</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="number" name="RequestsPerMinute" placeholder="Type maximum amount of reqs/min..." class="form-control valid"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Request Threshold</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="number" name="Threshold" placeholder="Type fastest timeframe for 1 request in seconds..." class="form-control valid"></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Comment</label><div class="col-sm-9"><textarea name="Comment" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea></div></div></form>
```

**The problem:**

Using the above code, it will still serialize empty fields (but I want to avoid that). This is the result `{ RequestsPerMinute: '121', Threshold: '', Comment: '' }` . How can I avoid serializing the fields without value?

Comment: Can you try removing the `:` from your `var form = $("#bulk-edit-fut-account-form :input[value!='']");`?

Comment: @TylerRoper actually that would be correct probably. Now it ignores my "comment" field which is a textarea and it still doesn't filter empty value fields. Looks like my idea didn't work as desired.

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if that works.

Comment: Why JSON, why on earth wouldn't you serialize it as x-www-form-encoded with `form.serialize()`

Comment: @adeneo Because I use websockets and I pass it along with other information. I simplified the problem here as much as possible. I also need it because of other reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var form = $(); //Initialize empty jQuery object

    //Iterate through all inputs, textareas
    $('#bulk-edit-fut-account-form input, #bulk-edit-fut-account-form textarea').each(function() {

        //Add to jQuery object if not empty
        if ($(this).val().length) {
           form = form.add($(this)); 
        }

    })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(form));
    var formData = getFormData(form);
```

Comment: I think the issue is that I didn't describe the problem properly. It's not about the "attribute" value, because it's an input textbox. I want to check if this textbox is empty or not. If it is empty => filter

Comment: What is the difference between an empty textbox and a textbox with no value? The example I have above says "If the textbox does not have a value, OR the textbox has a value that is blank, then exclude it".

Comment: I have tried your solution. It filters all fields, regardless if they have content or not.

Comment: I mean your other option would be to do an `$.each` for each input and textarea, and if there is a value, add it to `form`.

Comment: @kentor Sorry the previous solution didn't work. Can you try this newer one?

Comment: @kentor One last update on top of my most recent - Changed the array to a jQuery object to match your original script instead.

Comment: @kentor Saw your edit suggestion. I rejected it only because removing `#bulk-edit-fut-account-form` in front of `textarea` means *"Every textarea on the entire page"*, whereas `#bulk-edit-fut-account-form textarea` means *"textareas within `#bulk-edit-fut-account-form`"*. Unless this was your intention?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to modify the function

```
function getFormData($form, no_empty) {
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {};

    $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i) {
        indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });

    if (no_empty) {
        $.each(indexed_array, function(key, value) {
            if ( $.trim(value) === "" ) delete indexed_array[key];
        });
    }

    return indexed_array;
}
```

When you wan't to call it normally, and include everything, you just do

```
 var json = getFormData( form );
```

and when you don't want the empty inputs, you just do

```
 var json = getFormData( form, true );
```

and they are filtered out

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I use the method also at other places where I want to serialize empty fields. If there is no better solution I will try your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could `filter` and remove elements where `.val()` is empty:

```
$.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
    indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
}).filter(function() {
    // will be removed from array if empty
    return $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I use the method also at other places where I want to serialize empty fields. If there is no better solution I will try your answer.